# g_signal delays (C, GTK+)

Tags: c, gtk, gobject

I've got a little GTK-Application with two buttons (**A**, **B**) and a drawing area (**C**).
When I click on **A**, **C**'s size should be recalculated and set with gtk_widget_set_size_request(). This will cause an *expose-event*, whose handler will calculate some data. Further, the click on **A** will emit a *clicked* signal at **B**, whose handler needs the data calculated by **C**'s *expose-event*.

In fact everything works fine, but the *expose-event* delays somehow, and the *clicked* handler is called before and the data (you may guess it) is missing.

```
a_handler() {
   new_size = calculate_size();
   gtk_widget_set_size_request(C, new_size); //Will cause expose-event
   g_signal_emit_by_name(B, "clicked");
}

b_handler() {
   calculate_something(data); //Error
}

c_handler() {
   draw_something();
   data = calcluate_data();
}
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ugly fix is typically to add calls to `gtk_main_iteration()`, for instance between the call to `gtk_widget_set_size_request()` and the signal-emission.

Comment: Hey dude, that's perfekt! Just use `while (gtk_events_pending())
  gtk_main_iteration();`

Answer (score 1):

Gtk (and most other GUI toolkits) does the painting and event handling all in one thread. Therefore when the expose event is emitted, it goes into a queue and will be handled only after `a_handler` returns.

The best approach in my opinion would be to move the calculation somewhere else, if there is not some good reason to tie it into GUI drawing. For example, there could be a separate method `calculate_data` that is called both from `b_handler` and `c_handler`.

The next best way is to call `gdk_window_process_updates` to force the expose event to be handled immediately:
http://developer.gnome.org/gdk/stable/gdk-Windows.html#gdk-window-process-updates

Comment: But there is a good reason to tie it into GUI drawing, that's the problem. This "calculation" is very computationally intensive and to be more precise it's somewhat like that:


`c_handler() {  


   for() {  
      data = calcluate_data();  
      draw_something(data);  
   }  
}`  

(I'm afraid I don't get this correct, damn!)